# How to create a fields on the users profile to allow them choose from a number of opens then order them based on preference

Tags: 7, entities

On the users profile, I need to add the ability for users to select from a number of options, then order them based on their preference.

e.g.

What are your favorite fruits?

Select from:

Apples

Bananas

Oranges

Grapes

Then I need the users to be be able to reorder them in terms of preference:

e.g.

Grapes

Bananas

Apples

Any thoughts on how to achieve this (existing modules)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's D7, user profiles are fieldable, so you've got what you want out of the box : add a field in admin/config/people/accounts/fields with a select wodget and you're done.

For the ordering, I think [Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) could be worth a look.